# Plotly heatmap in r - col and row labels don't fit resulted chart

Tags: r, plotly

I took simple plotly heatmap example and tried to change horizontal and vertical labels of resulted heatmap.

```
    plot_ly(
  x = c("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb", "ccccccccccccccccccccccccc"), 
  y = c("rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr", "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu", "fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff"),
  z = m, type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))
```

But vertical labels seem to be very unstructured of what I'm expecting. From the top I should have r, then u and f. Instead of that I have u, r, f. What I'm doing wrong?

How can i keep order for rows and columns same as I defined in x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `autorange = "reversed"`:

```
library(plotly)
plot_ly(
  x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = c("r", "u", "f"),
  z = m, type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(autorange = "reversed"))
```

Which gives:

[image]

Comment: When I use that for my solution, where I have quite long x and y labels, noRows=noCols = 7, it doesn't work... That's weird.

Comment: @martinkabe Please provide a reproducible example of your situation so I could look into it (ideally a `dput()` of your data)

Comment: What for package version do you use?  I'm pretty sure this is a problem with the newest one, as it does not work for me as well.

Comment: @Jimbou Most probably, I haven't upgraded to the latest version as it would require me to revisit lots of previously made graphs part of elaborate dashboards. I'm still using `v3.6.0`. I think maybe you or the OP should open an issue ?

Comment: I'm using plotly_4.5.2 ver. Now I'm using d3heatmap and it works fine. But even d3heatmap is not good idea in ioslides_presentation - d3heatmap is visible in the previous slide...

It seems to we have two issues...